# Implementing UI services with HTML services within a sites page

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to wrap my head around some concepts and trying to extend the help desk exercise in the process. What I am trying to accomplish is the following:

Within the site, create a "re-usable" page and create multiple links in the navigation like:

- https://sites.google.com/a/mydomain.org/helpdesk/tickets?status=new
- https://sites.google.com/a/mydomain.org/helpdesk/tickets?status=open

This Page, contains an HTML Service which reads the query string parameters and proceeds to query a spreadsheet for all tickets with the specified status and that are assigned to the current user, then displays them in a table format.

Then on the table, on each line, there will be a button that says "add solution or comment", this will open a UI service that allows the user to enter some text and change status if necessary.

So my questions are:
Does this sound feasible? Can I call a UI service from an HTML template service?
Can the HTML Service read the query string parameters?
Any examples of this?

Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **can not** mix UI service with HTML service. Once you're using one you have to stick with it.

But what you described can be easily done using either one. i.e. showing a table with some info and a button per row, that will show a textbox. So, yes, this is perfectly feasible.

Reading the url parameters can be easily done on "server-side", that is, it's independent if you're using Html or Ui Services.

Example of reading parameters? Here it is:

```js
function doGet(e) {
  var status = e.parameter.status;
  if( status == 'new' ) {
    //do your thing

  } else if( status == 'open' ) {
    //just examples

  } else
    ;//bad status

  return appOrHtml;
}
```